# sql find match where record of one type exists but the other does not

Tags: sql, join

I have the following (abridged schema) - 3 tables - user, job, job_type

```
TABLE: job_type
COLUMN: job_type_id
1           
2

TABLE: user
COLUMN: user_id
101
102
103

TABLE: job
COLUMNS: job_id | user_id | job_type_id
              4 |     101 |           1
              5 |     101 |           2
              6 |     102 |           1
              7 |     103 |           2
```

I want to write a query that returns all of the users who have a job in the job table where job_type_id = 1, but if they ALSO have a job with job_type_id = 2, to exclude them from the results.  Therefore, the target resultset should return back user 102 only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't indicate what DBMS you're using, but here are some queries that should work in almost any:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
  FROM job j1
 WHERE job_type_id = 1
   AND NOT EXISTS
        ( SELECT 1
            FROM job j2
           WHERE job_type_id = 2
             AND j2.user_id = j1.user_id
        )
;

SELECT DISTINCT user_id
  FROM job
 WHERE job_type_id = 1
   AND user_id NOT IN
        ( SELECT DISTINCT user_id
            FROM job
           WHERE job_type_id = 2
        )
;

SELECT DISTINCT j1.user_id
  FROM job j1
  LEFT
 OUTER
  JOIN job j2
    ON j1.user_id = j2.user_id
   AND j1.job_type_id = 1
   AND j2.job_type_id = 2
 WHERE j2.user_id IS NULL
;
```

Some DBMSes also offer a special `MINUS` or `EXCEPT` feature that you can use. That would look something like this:

```
SELECT user_id
  FROM job
 WHERE job_type_id = 1
MINUS                          -- or EXCEPT
SELECT user_id
  FROM job
 WHERE job_type_id = 2
;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
  from user u
 where exists (select * from job j
                where j.user_id=u.user_id
                  and j.job_type_id=1)
   and not exists (select * from job j
                    where j.user_id=u.user_id
                      and j.job_type_id=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Select * from
user U inner join Job J
on 
  J.user_id = U.user_id
inner join job_type T
on 
  T.job_type_id = 1
Where 
T.job_type_id <> 2
```